# How to use Ignore case here?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

In my code below:

```
  d={ 'h' : 'hhh' , 'l' : 'lll'}
  enpattern = re.compile(r'(.)\1?')
  str='HeLlo'
  result = [x.group() for x in enpattern.finditer(str)]
  data=''.join(map(lambda x:D.get(x,x),result))
  print data
```

This code takes each char from string and compares it with the key in dictionary and gives me the corresponding value. But here How can I ignore the CASE sensitivity when using finditer() method?

Answer (score 1):

As per your comments, you want to get `hhhellllllo`, so this is what you expect

```
result = [m.lower() for x in enpattern.finditer(my_string) for m in x.group()]
data   = ''.join(map(lambda x: d.get(x, x),result))
```

And don't name your variables as `str`, as that shadows the builtin [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) function

**Note:** You don't need RegEx at all to get that output. Its a simple one-liner

```
print ''.join(map(lambda x: d.get(x, x), my_string.lower()))
# hhhellllllo
```

Comment: Tried it but it does not work. i get output as - hhheLlo

Comment: @NBA What is the expected output?

Comment: hhhellllllo , re.compile(r'(.)\1?' was to identify double occurrence of a single char.

Comment: @NBA Then you shouldn't be having `?` in the RegEx

Comment: So does this- (.)\1? means one or more occurrence of a char?

Comment: @NBA Actually now I get what you are trying to do. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: @NBA But what I don't understand is why do you want to get the double occurance?